# Displaying ONLY filename and file permissions

Tags: bash

I am trying to list all files in the current directory that have a file size higher than a variable set by the user:

```
find . -type f -size +$filesize
```

This returns the correct files over the file size set by the user, but I cannot figure out how to display the permissions alongside it.

Desired format:

```
FILENAME FILEPERMISSION
```

Comment: Don't forget `find` is recursive and will also list all files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

According to [find(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) , something like this should work.

```
find -type f -size +$filesize -printf "%s\t %M\t %p \n"
```

Untested, as I am not on a linux box atm.

Comment: All I had to do was change the format around, but yeah, works great thank you so much!

Comment: @JoshuaBrown Please, take a look at this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).